# Merge field for base login URL in community welcome email?

Tags: email-template, customer-community, url, merge-field

I have set up a community and I am using a plain text email template for the welcome email.  I would like to mention the community's base login URL in the email body so that users can bookmark it.  Example: https://mycomm.force.com/s/login or even just https://mycomm.force.com/

However, when I use `{!Community.Url}` in the email, the URL includes the very long token which seems to indicate a brand-new user, like this:

> Please bookmark the MyComm community login URL:
>   https://mycomm.force.com/login?c=[very long token here]

I tried `{!Network_Community_Url}` and nothing appears at all.

Is there any merge field that will give me just the community's base URL in the email?

Answer (score 0):

`{!Network_Community_Url}` is what you are probably looking for.

Ref: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=merge_fields_communities.htm&type=5

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I tried {!Network_Community_Url} already and I get no URL at all.

Comment: Tried all of the merge fields in the doc and none of them give you the URL on its own. Unless HTML/VF templates are an option, I don't think you'll be able to get it without the token in a welcome email without hard coding it somewhere.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a formula with the mergefield in the template:

{! LEFT(Community.Url, (FIND("?", Community.Url) - 1)) }

It worked for me.